# No beans of 'DSLContext' type found

Tags: spring, intellij-idea, spring-boot, jooq

I have started to implement spring boot app using jooq for database access. I have integrated jooq like this sample project https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/master/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-jooq . My query works, but I am annoyed by IntelliJ underlining my DSLContext variable and giving me the error message "Could not autowire. No beans of 'DSLContext' type found". But because it works I guess it is created by spring-boot-starter-jooq? Am I doing something wrong? Should I create @Bean for DSLContext myself?

Also when I remove @Component annotation, then IntelliJ does not complain about create field and that it could not autowire it :/

[image]

Comment: I think you should file a bug to IntelliJ. In any case, I think there's some information missing here. E.g. how *do* you create that `DSLContext`?